# Where has the XML Data Binding Wizard in Delphi XE2 gone?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, xml-binding

[Embarcadero help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_the_XML_Data_Binding_Wizard) indicates that the XML Data Binding Wizard is also in XE2 (as well as XE and earlier) but I cannot see it (on two machines). Has it moved? Did it not get into XE2 yet? Is there a file I can add to install it? I can continue to generate classes using XE but I was about to unistall XE.....!

Comment: Found it. XE2 hides it completely unless you have a project open - XE simply greyed it.

Comment: Jesus. What wrong with the new Delphi version. I searched A LOT for that menu! Why they hide it this way? Thanks for posting this info here!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's still there. You have to have an open project first. Try this:

1. File->New->VCL Forms Application - Delphi
2. File->New->Other-XML - you'll see `XML Data Binding`.

It pretty much makes sense; you can't do much with an `XML Data Binding` without a project to use it.

Comment: True, but the XE behavior of showing the item grayed out makes more sense, because at least you know it's there.

Comment: Accepted anyway for your kind typing :-)

Comment: Brian, thanks. :) @Johan, I didn't start XE to check, as it wasn't what the question asked about; however, disabling an item without giving the user an explanation of how to enable it is considered bad UI design by some peoople, so the decision to leave it out might be based on that concept. But I don't work for EMBT, so I can't say one way or the other. :)

Comment: Sorry Ken didn't mean to upset you.

Comment: @Johan, I'm not upset. I'm just not sure why you were criticizing my answer when all I did was explain where and how to find what Brian was trying to find. :)